# Hashing function: Generate unique 3 letters Identifier

Tags: hash, key-generation

I need to create an id generation function that takes 4-digit number and returns a unique 3-letter identifier.

I already have a function that generates a 2-letter id from 3-digit number with some limitations (between 100 and 775), but I'm not sure how to change it to meet the new requirement.

```
if order_id < 775:
  alphabet = list('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')
  alpha_index = ''
  _i_1 = 0
  _i_2 = 0
  if order_id >=100 and order_id < 775:
    increment = 4*int((order_id-100)/100)
    _mod_100 = order_id%100
    if _mod_100 > 25 :
      _i_1 = (_mod_100/25)+increment
      _i_2 = _mod_100%25
      alpha_index += alphabet[int(_i_1-1)]
      alpha_index += alphabet[int(_i_2-1)]
    else:
      index = str(order_id)[1]+str(order_id)[2]
      index = int(index)
      if increment:
        alpha_index = alphabet[increment-1]
      alpha_index += alphabet[index] 
    alpha_order_id = alpha_index+str(order_id)[3:]
else:
  alpha_order_id = order_id
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: $26^3 = 17576 > 9999$. just multiply by $x$ take mod 17576?

Comment: This is an elementary programming question, with no relevance to cryptography.

Comment: @fgrieu No relevance at all? Nothing? Hashing - no? Uniqueness of response - no? Introduction to cryptographic hashes (the solution)  - no? Universal hashing - no? This isn't how to grow the user base fgrieu.

Comment: @fgrieu I'm not sure what's elementary about it and why it was marked as "off-topic". I don't have experience in cryptography and was hoping to get some help. I clearly explained the problem and showed attempt. Please advise on where to ask this question if this place is not the suitable place for it (DBA, SO...)

Comment: The question as asked is not about cryptography: the only mention of hash is in the title, not in the problem statement. This is about a change of numeration basis: from 4 digits in base 10 to 3 digits|characters in base 26. Base change is elementary math/computer science, not cryptography. Hint: for the reason in the first comment, any combination of 4 digits in base 10 can be expressed as 3 digits|characters in base 26.

Comment: @fgrieu how should the third letter be generated in the above solution to guarantee a unique output every time from a 4-digit number? I'm looking for a way to change the above solution to support this. Any other hints or algorithms to research are appreciated.

Comment: I'll give an example and let you write the code (that I suggest you do from scratch). Say you want to convert 9876 to 3 digits|characters in base 26. We compute 9796%26=22, coded by character `W`. There remains to encode 9796//26=379. We compute 379%26=15, coded by character `P`. There remains to encode 379//26=14 (we know that outcome is less than 26 for the reason kelalaka gave in comment), coded by character `O`. Often, in base change, we write the result with the first obtained character on the right: `OPW`. Again, that's base change or encoding.

Comment: Rather than your code, how about a cryptographic hash function, e.g. SHA-x/ MD5? And so `H(input) >> n` where n is an appropriate number of shift rights to get 3 characters. Since you're going 4 to 3, look up Pigeon Hole principle, and what a surjection is. And the difference between a simple hash function like Java's hashCode and a cryptographic one.